# Sveltekit static website blog show data filtered on client current date

Tags: typescript, static, svelte, blogs, sveltekit

Disclaimer: I'm a non-web engineer trying to setup a personal blog with sveltekit.

What I want: a static blog (hosted on github pages for now). I want to write blogposts ahead of time and have them show only when their published date is reached, so e.g. I set the published date for 2023-11-01, then it will only be shown if reloading the page from that date onwards.

Is this possible? How?

Code:

```
-- svelte.config.js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

const config = {
    ...
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
    }
}

-- +layout.ts
export const prerender = true;

-- BlogPosts.svelte
<script>
    export let posts: BlogPost[];
</script>

<section>
    <ul class="posts">
        {#each posts as post}
            <li class="post">
                <a href={post.slug} class="title">{post.title}</a>
                ...
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</section>

-- +page.svelte
<script>
    export let data;
</script>

<BlogPostList posts={data.postsAsOfToday} />

-- +page.ts
export async function load({ fetch }) {
    // the endpoint simply returns all blogposts from markdown files in the same repo
    const response = await fetch(base + '/api/blog');
    const posts: BlogPost[] = await response.json();
    const dateToday = new Date();
    const postsAsOfToday = posts.filter((post) => new Date(post.date) <= dateToday);
    return { postsAsOfToday };
}
```

But I can clearly see how `npm run build` will create the static html as of build time and only display that, regardless of the current `new Date()` when loading the webpage. Shouldn't it however be possible to have some javascript filter these posts on the client side "at runtime" while still keeping it a "static" blog?

Edit: This also leads to the same behavior:

```
--- BlogPosts.svelte
{#each posts as post}
    {#if new Date(post.date) <= new Date()}
        ...
    {/if}
{/each}
```

Comment: It is possible, but the data is still there on the client, meaning that anyone with some basic knowledge can see the data you filtered out.  if however you filter the posts at _build time_ (in your load functions) they will not.  This would of course mean you have to build everytime you 'publish'  a post.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Exactly, I would like to avoid building the entire blog whenever there's a new blogpost. Overall, I'm trying to separate between changes to the content (the posts) and changes to the blog itself (the website).